# App submitted invalid meta data

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

Whilst voting to close this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/q/34268281/746736

I received the following alert:

> The app submitted invalid meta data. Please let us know in meta.

... or something along those lines

- App Version: 1.4.1
- Device: iPhone 6
- OS Version: Version 9.1 (Build 13B143)

Comment: That error message, "The app submitted an invalid request. Please let us know on meta.", shows up on Bad Parameter, Access Token Required, No Method, and Key Required errors.  My guess is that the question got closed as you were submitting your close vote and the API rejected the now non-existent close reason as a bad parameter.